# How to understand $e$ and other terms in this probability distribution?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, random-variables, infinitary-combinatorics

Algebraically, the derivation of the probability function of a Poisson random variable is fairly straightforward. Letting $\mu = np$ with $n \to \infty, p \to 0$ so that $\mu < \infty$:

Starting with the intuitive:

$$P(X = x) = \binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$$

And ending up with seemingly, less obviously, intuitive:

$$P(X = x) = \frac{ e^{-\mu} \mu ^x }{ x! }$$

**My Question**

My question is, how can the Poisson probability function be understood intuitively so that it can be written immediately, just as the binomial.

**My Attempt**

I start off by breaking down the derivation:

First, $\mu = np$.

In finite terms, I understand this to scale $p$ up to the size of the population, so that whenever we draw $n$ samples, we expect that $\mu = np$ will be *successes,* for some definition of success. 
Analogously, having drawn infinite samples, $\mu = np$ seems to give us the expected number of successes. Without dependence on the sample size, I expect this to mean that regardless of the interval size, we always expect $\mu$ successes, which doesn't resonate too well with me.

The term $ \lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\mu / n)^n \sim e^{-\mu}$ seems to give the probability of *failing* infinite times.

I get more lost when I try to understand what the $\mu ^ x$ term means: why are we multiplying out the expected number of successes $x$ times?

I suspect that somewhere hidden in this compact equation lies a factor which accounts for all the different possible combinations of possible "orders of successes".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're not looking for this, but my understanding of the heuristic was a bit more based on the algebra. If you start with $\mu = np$ with $n$ large (and $p$ small), then (for fixed $x$, very small compared with $n$)
\begin{align*}
\binom nx p^x(1-p)^{n-x} &= \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}\left(\frac\mu n\right)^x\left(1-\frac\mu n\right)^{n-x} \\
&= \frac{\mu^x}{x!}\underbrace{\left(1-\frac\mu n\right)^n}_{\approx e^{-\mu}} \underbrace{\frac{n(n-1)\dots (n-x+1)}{n^x}\left(1-\frac\mu n\right)^{-x}}_{\approx 1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: This was my strategy to try to understand what's happening intuitively. What does each factor mean and how do they come together to intuitively get the result?

Comment: I think the probability of success in any interval of length $t$ should be given by a Poisson random variable with parameter $\mu t$. See, for example, pp. 144-5 of Ross, ninth edition.